# When I modify a const variable via a pointer, why is the original value not updated?

Tags: c++, constants, undefined-behavior

My professor gave me this code and told me that it has "Undefined Behaviour":

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    const int WEEKDAYS = 7;
    const int *pWeekdays = &WEEKDAYS;
    *((int*)pWeekdays) = 9;
    std::cout << WEEKDAYS;
    std::cout << *pWeekdays;

    return(0);
}
```

It gives the following output:

> 79

I am trying to understand the following:

1. Why is the behaviour undefined?
2. Why does printing `*pWeekdays` output `9` but printing `WEEKDAYS` outputs `7`?

Comment: You have undefined behaviour. You cannot expect this code to do anything reliable.

Comment: Modifying [a const is undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22656791/1708801), most likely since it is a const the compiler is replacing it with a literal and not even evaluating the variable.

Comment: @juanchopanza my professor called it that way... but I do not understand the behavior of these two variables.

Comment: It is an interesting question, although it is a duplicate, SO frowns on posting code as images.

Comment: The only thing to understand is that the program can do whatever it wants. You can look at the assembly code generated by this code on your particular platform to see exactly what is going on.

Comment: @Shafik Yaghmour I edited the question as you suggested. Thanks

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I've added some further improvements. I also agree that the question no longer deserves downvotes. The only thing wrong with it now is that it is a duplicate, but its already been closed for that reason.

Comment: @Shafik Yaghmour Thank you for your patience with my stumbling... I am learning the hard way, and accepting any condemns from this wonderful community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour because you are modifying a object that was declared `const`. You are not allowed to do this.

The reason that this is undefined behaviour is to allow the compiler to perform optimisations, which it appears to be doing in this case. It has replaced all instances of `WEEKDAYS` with the value `7`, so the first `cout` line becomes this:

```
std::cout << 7;
```

That's why it prints `7` regardless of what you do to the object that `pWeekdays` points at.

This behaviour is still undefined though. There's no reason it has to do this at all.

Comment: Thank You for opening my eyes.