# Why can't I change the value of a const data (int in my case) using const_cast

Tags: c++, const-cast

I have a piece of program as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int i = 100;
    cout<<"const i::"<<i<<endl;
    const_cast<int&>(i) = 200;
    cout<<"const i after cast::"<<i<<endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But the value of i is still 100. Aren't const_cast supposed to change the value of i?

Comment: This is [undefined behavior to attempt to modify a const](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22656734/1708801)

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb here and say a constant, by definition, cannot be changed.  It's constant.

Comment: Because trying to do so is undefined behavior (but I'm willing to bet that this is a duplicate).

Comment: "Aren't `const_cast` supposed to change the value of `i`?" No. It allows you to change a non-constant value if you've only got a constant reference to it; but nothing is supposed to change a constant value. It wouldn't be constant otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constant data is, by its very definition, *constant*, and attempting to change constant data leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).