# c++, How do two pointers to same location hold different values

Tags: c++, c, constants, compiler-optimization

Someone showed me the following code snippet and asked what it should output

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int value = 10;
    int* p = (int*)&value;
    *p = 20;

    cout << value << " " << *p << endl
        << &value << " " << p << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, there's a constant `value` which is 10, and there's a pointer `p` which points to the address of value, then the address pointed gets a different value.

I expected the program to print `20 20` [**but it actually prints `10 20`.**](http://ideone.com/lUyRZm)
It also shows that the two valuables have the same address. Can someone explain what's going on behind the scenes here?

Comment: Undefined behavior...?

Comment: @remyabel maybe but what happened?

Comment: See [How is a variable at the same address producing 2 different values?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22656734/1708801) ... attempting to modify a const object is undefined behavior this question is likely a duplicate.

Comment: @Shafik Not sure what question n.m. marked as a duplicate, but the one you linked seems like a fair duplicate. Is it really necessary to let the answerers gain rep for essentially repeating the same information?

Comment: @remyabel yes but I answered the question so I won't close it, there may be better duplicate but I don't have the time to look. See this [meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277126/1708801).

Comment: So you managed to break c++...nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Undefined behavior and an optimizing compiler. The compiler *knows* from `value`'s declaration that `value`'s value will never change in a well-formed program, so it optimizes out the bits where `value`'s value would be checked and just takes the value it knows `value` has.

As for the addresses, you never take the address of `p`, and that `p` is the same as `&value` is not surprising because you assigned it that way a few lines earlier.