# Can indirect change of volatile const be treated as undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, c, volatile, undefined-behavior

Does volatile write to volatile const introduce undefined behavior? What if I drop volatile when writing?

```
volatile const int x = 42;
const volatile int *p = &x;
*(volatile int *)p = 8; // Does this line introduce undefined behavior?
*(int *)p = 16; // And what about this one?
```

[Compilable code](http://codepad.org/aTRVq51D)

Comment: Related to [How is a variable at the same address producing 2 different values?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22656734/1708801)

Answer (score 8):

It is undefined behavior (for both statements) as you attempt to modify the "initial" `const` object. From C11 (N1570) 6.7.3/p6 *Type qualifiers* (emphasis mine):

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a
>   const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with **non-const-qualified
>   type**, the behavior is undefined.

For completeness it may be worth adding, that Standard says also that:

> If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a
>   volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue with
>   **non-volatile-qualified type**, the behavior is undefined.

Hence latter statement, that is:

```
*(int *)p = 16;
```

is undefined for second phrase as well (it's a "double UB").

I believe that rules are the same for C++, but don't own copy of C++14 to confirm.

Comment: Like my answer says, it's invalid to modify a `const` value - however, it is NOT invalid to remove `volatile` - it will just make the compiler potentially cache global values.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Hopefully my answer is more clear now. Yes, you are right, you can drop `volatile` qualifier and it's not UB to do that.

Comment: And the fact that constant is declared as volatile doesn't affect this statement?

Comment: @Qwertiy: It does not affect, because `const` already provoked an UB.

Comment: "If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined."    What kinds of actual bad/surprising behaviors could happen, beyond the loss of the optimization-defeating properties of `volatile`?

Comment: @Kaz: It means that particular language standard imposes no requirements, so theoretically _anything_ could happen. It may mean loss of data or even OS/hardware failure on some specific implementations, though it sound hardly unlikely. For modern implementations it may result into optimization drawbacks, but still you have no guarantee how to it would work (or not) on an other compiler.

Comment: What if it contradicts other requirements? Suppose ISO C or C++ suddenly were to acquire a clause which says "whenever two values of type `int` are added together whose mathematical sum is 42, the behavior is undefined".   Although this explicitly says that no requirement applies in that case, the remaining body of the document continues to give a requirement if we just ignore that conflicting sentence.  In this case, if we just remove that sentence, in fact the behavior can be deduced; all that is making it undefined is that sentence.

Comment: Okay, so a better question is perhaps: what useful feature can an implementation provide, which will break for programs which access the `volatile` object as non-`volatile`? (I.e. which is enabled by that statement in the standard?) What can a compiler do based on knowing that an object is declared `volatile`, which will break if something elsewhere accesses that object otherwise?

Comment: Sorry about the extended discussion,  Grzegorz. I opened a question about this on the Programmers SE: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/298193/benefit-of-non-volatile-access-to-volatile-objects-being-undefined    (I provide one hypothetical benefit in the question, to show some effort. )

Answer (score 5):

Writing to a variable that is originally `const` is undefined behaviour, so all your example writes to `*p` are undefined.

Removing `volatile` in itself is not undefined in and of itself.

However, if we have something like `const volatile int *p = (const volatile int*)0x12340000; /* Address of hw register */`, then removing `volatile` may cause the hardware to update the register value, but your program doesn't pick it up. (E.g. if we "busy wait" with `while(*p & 0x01) ;`, the compiler should reload the value pointed to by `p` every time, but `while((*(const int *)p) & 1) ;`, the compiler is entirely free to read the value ones, and re-use the initial value to loop forever if bit 0 is set).

<strike>You could of course have `extern volatie int x;` and then use `const volatile int *p = &x;` in some code, and `x` gets updated by some other piece of code outside of your current translation unit (e.g. another thread) - in which case removing either `const` or `volatile` is valid, but as above, you may "miss" updated values because the compiler doesn't expect the global value to get updated outside of your module unless you call functions.</strike> [Edit, no, taking away `volatile` by casting the value is also forbidden in the standard - it is however valid to add `const` or `volatile` to something, and then remove it again if it the original object referred to did not have it].

Edti2: `volatile` is needed to tell the compiler that "the value may change at any time, even if you think nothing should have changed it". This happens, in general, in two situations:

1. Hardware registers that are updated outside of the software altogether - such as status registers for a serial port, a timer-counter register, or interrupt status of the interrupt controller, to name a few case - there are thousands of other variations, but it's all the same idea: The hardware changes the value, without direct relation to the software that is accessing such registers.
2. Variabled updated by another thread within the process (or in case of shared memory, by another process) - again, the compiler won't be able to "see" such changes. Often, one can write code that appear to function correctly by calling a function inside wait-loops and such, and the compiler will the reload values of non-local variables anyway, but some time later the compiler decides to inline that function call, and then realizes that the code is not updating that value, so doesn't reload the value -> bug when you inspect the "updated" value and find the same old value that the compiler had already loaded earlier.

Note also that `volatile` is NOT a guarantee for any kind of thread/process correctness - it will just guarantee that the compiler doesn't skip over reads or writes to that variable. It is still up to the programmer to ensure that for example multiple values that are dependent on ordering are indeed updated in the correct order, and on systems where caches are not coherent between processing units, that the caches are made coherent via the software [for example a CPU and a GPU may not use coherent memory updates, so a write by the CPU does not reach the GPU until the cache has been flushed on the CPU - no amount of applying `volatile` to the code will fix this]

Comment: What do you mean by thread? If I place the same code into the other thread and wait until it finishes, is will the code become correct? Or you've meant the process?

Comment: What do you mean by remove. If you mean point to then it is undefined as well. *If an attempt is
made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue
with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: The part on `const` is correct, but your part about `volatile` looks wrong. C11 says *"If an attempt is
made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue
with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined."*

Comment: @Qwertiy: See edit 2. Any value that is updated by thread, process or external hardware, outside of the "current code" will need to use `volatile` for the value to be correctly re-read (or written in case of non-`const` variables).

Comment: @MatsPetersson, I still find what you write very confusing. For both `const` and `volatile` you can't simply remove such a qualifier. There are subtle differences, thought, and you'd have to be very careful here, because this also is a C and C++ question, and I think there are even subtle differences between them.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Thinking about it and looking at other answers in similar vein, it would appear that pre-C11 didn't state clearly what is and isn't allowed with casting away `volatile`, but C11 and C++11 both state that it's undefined. Of course, within undefined behaviour is the possibility of "it still works as expected".

Comment: @MatsPetersson: A major weakness of the Standard IMHO is that there is no behavioral category for things where *most* implementations will be able to specify a specific behavior, but some may be unable to define anything more specific than "unconstrained arbitrary behavior".  From a purely requirements-driven standpoint, such a category would be essentially equivalent to UB, but from a normative standpoint it would be very different.  IMHO, most things which are categorized as UB should have been characterized as "optionally-defined behaviors", with the implication that implementations...

Comment: ...should attempt to define them usefully even if they are not required to do so.  The semantics of volatile variables, as well as reads and writes thereof, are in general Implementation-Defined; an implementation spec would generally define the relationship among different types of memory reads even though the C spec does not.